# Find the real root of $x^5+5x^3+5x-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the real root of $$x^5+5x^3+5x-1$$

I have tried with squaring but the numbers that I got is not correct, any help ?

Answer (score 8):

Setting $x=y-\frac 1y$, equation is $y^{10}-y^5-1=0$

And so $$y=\sqrt[5]{\frac{1+\sqrt 5}2}$$ or $$y=\sqrt[5]{\frac{1-\sqrt 5}2}$$

And in both cases, we get $${x=\sqrt[5]{\frac{\sqrt 5+1}2}-\sqrt[5]{\frac{\sqrt 5-1}2}}$$

**AND WE'RE DONE**

Comment: +1 but Is there any technique you use to recongnize wether or not to use that method?

Comment: @OussamaBoussif: That technique can be used for polynomials that are symmetric in their coefficients: i.e. if you reverse the coefficients you get the same polynomial. The original question is equivalent to $$x^5+5x^3+5x+1=2$$ and the polynomials on both sides satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @OussamaBoussif Yes there is.

Comment: Ah thanks to both of you ^^